# How to get the aperture angle from a webcam with OpenCV?

Tags: c++, opencv, webcam, camera-calibration

I'm capturing the webcam images with OpenCV and C++ and tracking the persons face. So my problem is that I need the aperture angle to calculate the position of the person. How to get this angle?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to calibrate your camera using a standard calibration target like a chessboard. Look [here](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/camera_calibration_and_3d_reconstruction.html) for the OpenCV camera calibration API.

Comment: link broken, I will assume it this one [link](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/dc/dbb/tutorial_py_calibration.html)